# How to create a popup window with minimal decoration?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I want to open a popup window with minimal decoration.
I tried the following code:

```
<script>
newwindow =
      window.open('http://jquery.com','name',
        'height=300px,width=400px,scrollbars=no');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
</script>
```

Some decorations(menu bar,scroll bar,..) have been gone. But some decorations are still exist(title bar, address bar).

How to remove all the decorations? I want a cross-browser solution.

Comment: I think what you could try is a modal dialog using an internal iframe.  Just a thought.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Some web pages cannot be display in iframe because of x-frame-options.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options you can override it by using `target='_top'`

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee it is not working for me "<iframe src="http://drive.google.com" target="_top"></iframe>".